# Copy stream content on two destinations

Tags: c#, stream, copy

I know it's possible to copy one stream to another with `sourceStream.CopyTo(targetStream);` but I want to copy content of `sourceStream` to two destination streams in **two different `Task`s**. When I call this method two times, in second time stream is empty.

Is that possible at all? A simple way is to load stream content to memory then copy it on targets, but it may cause `OutOfMemoryException`.

If it matters I'm using .Net 4.5

Comment: Try setting `sourceStream.Position = 0;`, if seeking is supported, to reset the starting position?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt that assumes that `sourceStream` is seekable; many aren't

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're copying it to two destinations *at the same time*, then something like:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[SOME_SIZE];

int bytesRead;
while((bytesRead = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    dest1.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    dest2.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

This iterates through the input stream once, writing each chunk to two outputs. This is pretty much what `CopyTo` does internally - the only difference is the second output.

Comment: It's a clever and simple way to fix it, but I want to pass stream to two different `Task`s and let them copy the stream. If there is no built in way to do these, I think I must create a shared `byte[]` between this two task, yeah?

Comment: sharing a `byte[]` between two tasks sounds like a synchronization thread-race nightmare...

Comment: I know, I meant some thread safe structure, but is there any suitable structure for these situation?

Comment: @vakarami thread safety is also about the code that *uses* something, not the something itself; there's no simple answer to the question you ask

Comment: if somebody else comes across this, don't forget to set your stream positions back to the beginning after the copy.
dest1.Possition = 0;
dest2.Possition = 0;

Answer (score -1):

Copy stream as many times using the method below:

```
private static Stream CopyStream(Stream inputStream)
{
    const int readSize = 256;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[readSize];
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    int count = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, readSize);
    while (count > 0)
    {
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, count);
        count = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, readSize);
    }
    ms.Position = 0;
    return ms;
}
```

Use it as:

```
Stream destStream1 = CopyStream(sourceStream);
Stream destStream2 = CopyStream(sourceStream);
```

Comment: not all streams are seekable - most interesting ones : aren't

Comment: the problem with this solution is that stream content will be load to memory 2 times!