# Can I see the data that a Stream is sending to another Stream?

Tags: c#, tcp, proxy, stream

I want to be able to send data from a Network Stream to another Network Stream e.g `CopyToAsync` while being able to see the data that is being sent to the first Network Stream.

In my project im using the code below to send data in 2 seperate streams.

```
Task.WhenAny(ClientToProxy.CopyToAsync(ServerToProxy), ServerToProxy.CopyToAsync(ClientToProxy));
```

That works perfectley fine but im trying to see the data the ClientToProxy stream is reciving so i tried this code.

```
        byte[] data = new byte[2048];

        Task.WhenAny(ClientToProxy.ReadAsync(data, 0, data.Length), ServerToProxy.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length), ServerToProxy.CopyToAsync(ClientToProxy));
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", ""));
```

But then the data never gets sent from the ClientToProxy stream to the ServerToProxy stream.

Ive been trying to find a solution to this for 2 days now so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you are doing this circular `CopyToAsync`, what's the purpose? In any case, I think what you want to do is to [copy to multiple streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43717890/3034273) at the same time, so you can inspect one of the streams

Comment: I think this might work, ill give it a try and let you know how it goes!

Comment: By implementing the `CopyToAsync()` yourself, you can make the method copy to two separate streams simultaneously. See duplicate. Another approach would be to implement a `Stream` subclass that simply forwards all input from one stream out to another stream, while providing some kind of inspection of the data as it goes by (e.g. via event, a callback passed to a constructor, etc.). The latter approach is more "composable" and OOP-like, but of course would involve a lot more work than just writing your own `CopyToAsync()`.